# Aws Appsync $util.error: data and errorInfo always null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am playing with AWS AppSync. I am trying to output some error details when the request fails using the `$util.error()` helper ([Documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html)) in my resolver's response mapping template. No matter what I do, I am not able to get AppSync to output the `data` and `errorInfo` fields in the `error` output.

Here is the Lambda I have.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  callback(null, {
    data: {
      name: "Test",
    },
    errorMessage: "Some error Message",
    errorType: "SomeErrorType",
    errors: {
      "foo": "bar",
      "bazz": "buzz",
    }
  })
};
```

As you can see, it is pretty much straight forward. I just return an object with the `data`, `errors`, `errorMessage` and `errorType` properties.

And here is my response mapping template

```
$utils.error($context.result.errorMessage, $context.result.errorType, $context.result.data, $context.result.errors)
```

Again, pretty much straight forward. I just throw an error directly using the fields coming from the Lambda.

But when I execute the query, I get this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "myField": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "myField"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "SomeErrorType",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Some error Message"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the `errorType` and `message` fields get populated correctly, but not the `errorInfo` and `data` ones.

Am I missing something? Why isn't this working ?

I also tried hardcoding the parameters of `$util.error` in the template. I got the same result...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the documentation states, `Note: data will be filtered based on the query selection set`. So you need to return data that matches the selection set.

So, for a basic schema that looks like:

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String! 
}

type Query {
    simpleQuery: Post
}

schema {
    query: Query
}
```

And a query:

```
query {
  simpleQuery {
    title   // Note this selection set
  }
}
```

And a response mapping template:

```
$utils.error($context.result.errorMessage, $context.result.errorType, $context.result.data, $context.result.errors)
```

With a Lambda code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  callback(null, {
    data: {
      title: "Test",   // The same selection set
    },
    errorMessage: "Some error Message",
    errorType: "SomeErrorType",
    errors: {
      "foo": "bar",
      "bazz": "buzz",
    }
  })
};
```

It will return:

```
{
  "data": {
    "badOne": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "badOne"
      ],
      "data": {
        "title": "Test"
      },
      "errorType": "SomeErrorType",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 8,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Some error Message"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lisa, I tried that and I finally had it working. I was already returning an object that matched my query in the `data` section but my issue was that I was missing some required fields. When that happens, the `data` section returns null.
So, that fixes my issue with `data`.
However, what about the `errorInfo` section? In your example, it also returns null when it should have returned the `errors` attribute in my lambda response.

Comment: But the errorInfo is still null. Is there a way to get it to the client?

Answer (score 1):

For the `errorInfo`, you will need to update the template version to `2018-05-29`. 
See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53495843/2724342